Reference Request: a coherence result
I have been doing some work related to Grothendiek coherators in the sense given by Dimitri Ara and other authors and doing research that extends the idea. I am attempting to understand why given an $(\infty,0)$-coherator $C$ over the opposite category of table of dimensions $\Theta_0^{op}$, then every groupoid $G$ gives a $1$-truncated algebra
$$
\gamma_G:C\to Set.
$$
This is a type of coherence result I want to see the technical details of a proof because the actual proof itself would greatly help me.
I have felt in the literature that is just feels like it is accepted, but an actual citation for a concrete proof would be greatly appreciated.

Seems like a question suitable for mathoverflow.
